# how to get all images show in table in react without using require key in dynamic images in folder

Tags: reactjs

its only shows image in a folder and page not working
<Avatar variant="rounded"   src={require(`./upload/${value}`)  } >

Comment: <Avatar variant="rounded"   src={require(`./upload/${value}`)  } >
                    </Avatar>

Comment: it don't shows a without folder images